# Is possible get variable name from arraylist content? Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this variables and this Arraylist:

```
    String cod = ":)", desfondo = ":(", desCorFondo = ":|";
    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,cod,desfondo,desCorFondo));
```

I want something like this:

```
System.out.println(variableName from arraylist  + " " + list.get(1));
```

Output:

```
cod :)
```

Is it possible to get the variable name in some way, without having to use hashmap?

Comment: Maybe reflection is something to look into

Comment: For what you described, `List` is not right data structure.

Comment: I know, is only for concatenate Variable Name and value.

Comment: Consider using a `Map<String, String>`, where the key is effectively `variableName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all field name by reflection

```
Class yourClass = YourClass.class
Field[] fields = yourClass.getFields();
for(Field f: fields){
    f.getName();
}
```

And then use `Field.get()` expects the object which contains the field as argument. So you should have `field.get(object)`.

Since you appear to be looking for the field value, you can obtain that as:

```
Object objectValue = field.get(object);
```

You can use the above to get the value and perform the print like you intended. From my opinion list is not a good for what you want to do, ideally HashMap.